# Can oatmeal be cooked in rice milk in a regular oven and pan?

Tags: oven, oatmeal

I usually cook a big portion of oatmeal in a big plastic bowl with 1 liter of rice milk at 600W for 5-7 minutes in a microwave oven. however, I don't have one at my disposal at the moment.

Can the same process be done in a regular oven? If so, at what temperature? For how long?

Maybe I should use water instead or rice milk?

Comment: Hmm. Most recipes for oatmeal in the oven are for cookies or bars. But it should work for porridge too. I happen to have oatmeal and a pre-heated oven, so I'll give it a shot.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yep, you can make oatmeal in the oven. Mine turned out just fine, quite good in fact.

[image: oatmeal]

I used a small casserole dish with a lid in a 350F (180C) oven.

[image: Oatmeal in lidded casserole]

I heated 1 cup each of water and milk with a dash of salt in the covered casserole dish for 20 minutes which brought the liquid nearly to a boil. I stirred in 1 cup of old-fashioned oats (not quick-cooking), replaced the lid, and baked without stirring for 20 minutes.

So a 1:2 ratio of oats to nearly boiling liquid.

It is as good as any oatmeal I've ever made. Rice milk should work just as well, I'd go half and half with water the first time you do it, and definitely use a pot or dish (ovenproof, of course) with a tight-fitting lid.

See [Is there an easy way to tell if a pan/pot is oven-safe?](https://cooking.stackexchange.com/questions/64599/is-there-an-easy-way-to-tell-if-a-pan-pot-is-oven-safe) for advice concerning the cooking vessel. You can be pretty relaxed about any pan that is meant for stovetop use for this application because most modern cookware is made to withstand 350F (180C) easily - even non-stick surfaces or handles.