# How can I tell if a glass saucepan lid is oven safe?

Tags: oven, sauce-pan

I have a set of saucepas.
I recalls from when I got them that the silicon handle is oven safe, so that you could put them under the grill to finish.
But I don't recall if the glass lid is also oven-safe.
Its handle is also silicon, but that might just be to match

I am considering if I could use it to cook bread in the oven, as the particular bread I am using calls to be cooked in something with a lid, e.g. a cassarole dish, and my dutch oven is too large.

Related: [Is there an easy way to tell if a pan/pot is oven-safe?](https://cooking.stackexchange.com/questions/64599/is-there-an-easy-way-to-tell-if-a-pan-pot-is-oven-safe)

Comment: Would this help? https://expandusceramics.com/qa/is-glass-safe-in-oven.html

Comment: A pan lid should be more likely than a dish, as it's being heated by the air (via any metal parts) rather than being put onto a preheated shelf with stripes of hot metal - It's usually thermal stress that breaks things